# How to change timezone in recovery mode?

Tags: terminal, timezone

I have a MacBook pro and I'm trying to instal OS X El Capitan on a clean formatted SSD hard drive. While installing I encounter an error saying "this copy of the instal os x el capitan application can't be verified...". After some search in the internet I realized the problem is due to date and time being not correct. I corrected the time but I couldn't find a way to change the time zone because whenever I type "systemsetup" command I receive the "command not found" error.
I will be more than happy if anyone can help me with this problem.
Thanks

Comment: If the linked Q&A doesn't answer your question, please edit it to indicate in more detail what you have tried and where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216730/this-copy-of-the-install-os-x-el-capitan-application-cant-be-verified-it-may-h), try setting the date to one earlier than the current date. The timezone should not matter at the time of installation.