# MacBook Pro 2015 won’t boot to Operating System. Constantly restarts at Apple logo screen

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, battery

I have tried all the obvious commands at boot without success, including Safe Mode. Then booted into Single-User mode. Ran “fsck -fy” command. Shows 9 line item warnings: “time stamp is invalid. Is greater than current time”.   Rebooted and ran a hardware check which showed the battery needed to be replaced. Will replace the internal battery today, but not sure how to reset the date in Single-user mode. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @Stevo, I think it would be useful to know which system version is in use on your machine.

Comment: Try booting in [Verbose Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) hold `Cmd-V` while booting. See if you can see what messages appear on the screen. Also, can you boot to Recovery?

Comment: Tried Cmd-V but scrolling is so fast can’t read if there’s any error messages. Then tries to reboot but just keeps rebooting.

Comment: Running Mojave...

Comment: Try recording with a camera so you can stop and read the messages

Comment: It might be worth to have a look at this post https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216730/this-copy-of-the-install-os-x-el-capitan-application-cant-be-verified-it-may-h/230012 . Although it does not meet your issue exactely, in this post several people evaluated date-time-issues related to installation problems. Perhaps you'll be able to find an idea on how to fix your problem.

Comment: “fsck -fy”  checks out your startup partition.  Your file system has gotten corrupted. You choices are to use a better file system recovery tool, reformat you dive & loose all you data or get an external drive. Install macos on the drive or restore from backup.  Hold done the option key at poweron to pick your boot drive.

Comment: could try setting a later date from the command line then booting from the command line. how to set the date: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTdV7IWLQ3Y