# iMac mid 2007 verification error during install OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos

The error comes on iMac mid 2007 and I didn't get sufficient replies or successful method after seeing above mention posts.

Comment: Álî Ali: I believe all the answers given in the [duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216730/this-copy-of-the-install-os-x-el-capitan-application-cant-be-verified-it-may-h) are outdated. Where did you get the El Capitan installer? I ask because the current download of El Capitan from [this Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) should work. If you are still having difficulties, post a comment.

Comment: I added pertinent up to date info to the highest voted answer on there to save people having to scroll right the way down to find the newest.